# How to automatically eliminate the file name from the url?

Tags: php, apache, friendly-url

I'm already using RewriteEngine and RewriteConditions to eliminate the .php part from the file name.

However, I visited this site recently, `http://poorlydrawnlines.com/comic/tragedy/`. In it, just to mess around, I tried finding the actual file name, which turned out to be index.php. However, when I tried to go to `http://poorlydrawnlines.com/comic/tragedy/index.php`, the site automatically shortens the url to `http://poorlydrawnlines.com/comic/tragedy/`. How is this behavior achieved?

Also, am I correct in assuming that the page's original address ends in index.php? Or is the site simply redirecting me? How do I recreate this in my own websites?

Comment: That is achieved by exact the means of url rewriting you already claim you use. Actually if you do so then the solution should be obvious to you. URL rewriting can not only internally rewrite an incoming request, it can also redirect your browser, which is what you see in the example.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do it? I use the code I found on some site, but I don't yet understand how exactly the rewriteEngine works.

Comment: @arkascha also, will an apache book help me in learning these concepts? Are these generally included in the common apache books, such as O'Reily's Apache Cookbook?

Comment: I suggest you start reading the documentation. You _cannot_ develop without doing so. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html That makes much more sense than a book in my eyes. The documentation is of excellent quality and comes with really good examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not provided your original `.htaccess` code this is the best i can do.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply adjust your RewriteCondition to look for index.php in the requested URL and remove it instead of removing just the .php extension.

EDITED to give example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "(.*)/index\.php"
RewriteRule ".*" "%1/" [R=301,L]
```

The RewriteCond is used to capture the folder/path  name and then RewriteRule redirects to it without the filename. This also preserves any query string parameters.

Comment: Oh.. that makes sense. Can you provide an example code to do it?

Comment: A `RewriteCondition` cannot do any action. You refer to a `RewriteRule`...

Comment: Correct, RewriteCondition cannot do the action, but it can capture the original path, which can then be used in the RewriteRule.

Comment: cmorrisssey's solution works the same way but is more concise. I'd recommend going with his instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @cmorrissey answer, this script will also do the trick, without `mod_rewrite`:

```
$lookup = 'index.php';
$parts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if(substr($parts[0], -(strlen($lookup))) == $lookup){
    header('location: ./');
    die();
}
```